# Beget "doesn't see" DEBUG=False

Tags: django, virtualhost

I am hosting my test site on Beget and installed Django on it using CMS.
I set the DEBUG=False in settings.py, but I think it "doensn't know" about it, because it's still showing me the Django introduction page, despite the fact that I've changed urls.py too and it must return my template.

Also it keeps throwing this error
"The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead".

Now it's trying to fetch 'http://domain/favicon.ico' and it throws 404.

I don't know why is it like that.
Can someone help me?

EDITED:
The last 404 error disappeared, lol